# LINQ multiple order by

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, sql-order-by

I have created a function that has the follwing parameter:

```
List<Expression<Func<CatalogProduct, bool>>> orderBy = null
```

This parameter is optional, If it is filled it should create a order by and than by constuction for me, so that I can order the result on the SQL server.

I tried:

```
            IOrderedQueryable temp = null;
            foreach (Expression<Func<CatalogProduct, bool>> func in orderBy)
            {
                if (temp == null)
                {
                    temp = catalogProducts.OrderBy(func);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp.ThanBy(func);
                }
            }
```

But the than By is not reconized. Does someone know how I can solve this problem?

---

I changed it to .ThenBy() but this is only allowed directly after the .OrderBy() and not on a IOrderedQueryable

so temp = catalogProducts.OrderBy(func).ThenBy(func); is allowed but temp = catalogProducts.OrderBy(func); temp = temp.ThenBy(func); issn't

Any other suggestions?

Comment: This is a English usage error, not a programming error!

Comment: See updated answer re your update.

Comment: Comment from Jon, re-posted from your now-deleted answer:  "ThenBy is allowed on an IOrderedQueryable; it's not allowed on a plain IQueryable. Are you sure you've declared temp correctly"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two problems; firstly, `ThanBy` should be `ThenBy`; secondly, `ThenBy` is only available on the *generic* type, `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

So change to:

```
        IOrderedQueryable<CatalogProduct> temp = null;
        foreach (Expression<Func<CatalogProduct, bool>> func in orderBy) {
            if (temp == null) {
                temp = catalogProducts.OrderBy(func);
            } else {
                temp = temp.ThenBy(func);
            }
        }
```

and you should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   IOrderedQueryable temp = null; 
   foreach (Expression<Func<CatalogProduct, bool>> func in orderBy) 
    { 
      if (temp == null) 
        { 
          temp = catalogProducts.OrderBy(func);
        } 
        else
        { 
          temp = temp.OrderBy(func); 
        } 
     }
```

Comment: That will reorder *from scratch* each time. For multiple orderings, you really ought to use `ThenBy`.

Comment: Calling a second `OrderBy` will, depending on the implementation, either do the sorts in the reverse order, *or* only sort by the last one.

Comment: @Jon - not *quite* necessarily; remember that LINQ sort is meant to be stable, so this just reverses the sort sequence.

Comment: @Marc: True. It's basically not the right way to go though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (Expression<Func<CatalogProduct, bool>> func in orderBy)
        {
            catalogProducts = catalogProducts.OrderBy(func);
        }
```

This will be OK.