# How to pass multiple Expressions to OrderBy for EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF 4.2, but I expect this would apply to EF 4 and 4.1 as well.

I would like to pass an `IQueryable<T>` and multiple `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` to a method and have the method apply `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to the `IQueryable<T>` as appropriate.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047561/how-to-pass-an-array-of-orderby-expression-to-a-method/5235197#5235197), and wrote the method below based on that:

```
public IQueryable<User> ApplyOrderBy(IQueryable<User> query, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<User, IComparable>>> orderBy)
{
    if (orderBy == null) 
    {
        return query;
    }

    IOrderedQueryable<User> output = null;

    foreach(var expression in orderBy)
    {
        if (output == null)
        {
            output = query.OrderBy(expression);
        }
        else
        {
            output = output.ThenBy(expression);
        }
    }

    return output ?? query;
}
```

This works fine as long as the properties I order by are `string`s, but when I try to order by an `int` property, I get an exception:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.IComparable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Any suggestions to work around this, or for a different approach altogether?  I considered passing in an `IEnumerable<Expression>`, but then would need to figure out how to cast back to the specific type (e.g. `Expression<Func<User, int>`) to call `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I cannot explain why using an `Int32` does not work but using a `string`. Aren't both EDM "primitive" types and do not both implement `IComparable`? I don't understand the different behaviour.

Anyway, it seems to be necessary to pass in every expression in the collection with the concrete type it should be sorted by to avoid the failing type cast. In other words not an `IComparable`, but instead an `int`, a `string`, a `DateTime`, etc.

I had success to achieve this along the lines of the idea in this answer: [How to check for the presence of an OrderBy in a ObjectQuery<T> expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225481/how-to-check-for-the-presence-of-an-orderby-in-a-objectqueryt-expression-tree/225749#225749)

Define an interface which does *not* depend on the type to sort by but only the entity type. (The example below is generalized to arbitrary entities. If you only want that for `User` remove the generic parameter and replace `TEntity` in the queryables by `User`.)

```
public interface IOrderByExpression<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ApplyOrderBy(IQueryable<TEntity> query);
    IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ApplyThenBy(IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> query);
}
```

Define an implementation of that interface which now takes the type to sort by as a second generic parameter:

```
public class OrderByExpression<TEntity, TOrderBy> : IOrderByExpression<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> _expression;
    private bool _descending;

    public OrderByExpression(Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> expression,
        bool descending = false)
    {
        _expression = expression;
        _descending = descending;
    }

    public IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ApplyOrderBy(
        IQueryable<TEntity> query)
    {
        if (_descending)
            return query.OrderByDescending(_expression);
        else
            return query.OrderBy(_expression);
    }

    public IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ApplyThenBy(
        IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> query)
    {
        if (_descending)
            return query.ThenByDescending(_expression);
        else
            return query.ThenBy(_expression);
    }
}
```

Then `ApplyOrderBy` would look like this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyOrderBy<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query,
    params IOrderByExpression<TEntity>[] orderByExpressions)
    where TEntity : class
{
    if (orderByExpressions == null)
        return query;

    IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> output = null;

    foreach (var orderByExpression in orderByExpressions)
    {
        if (output == null)
            output = orderByExpression.ApplyOrderBy(query);
        else
            output = orderByExpression.ApplyThenBy(output);
    }

    return output ?? query;
}
```

And it can be used the following way:

```
var query = context.Users ... ;

var queryWithOrderBy = ApplyOrderBy(query,
    new OrderByExpression<User, string>(u => u.UserName),    // a string, asc
    new OrderByExpression<User, int>(u => u.UserId, true));  // an int, desc

var result = queryWithOrderBy.ToList(); // didn't throw an exception for me
```

The need to specify the generic type parameters explicitely in the `OrderByExpression` instances is not nice but I couldn't find a way so that the compiler infers the types. (I was hoping it would, because the compiler infers the `User` as `TEntity` from `query` for the `ApplyOrderBy` method, then I expected that it knows the `TEntity` of `OrderByExpression` (equals `User` as well). So the lambda parameter `u` should be known as a `User` and then the compiler could derive the type from  `UserName` as `string` and from `UserId` as `int`. But this theory is apparently wrong. The compiler complains and wants to have the generic types explicitly.)

Comment: +1, Great answer, it works perfectly and is exactly what I was hoping for :)

Comment: I've been struggling with this, and will probably give up, but I recon it should be possible to use Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>, then when you call ApplyOrderBy inspect the Lambda expression, find out the type of the parameter, then build a new Lambda expression properly typed. Seems like too much hard work though.

Comment: More than great, terrific answer, I hope I could upvote this 1000 times.