# Sorting with OrderBy, ThenBy

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, iorderedenumerable

I'm trying to sort several columns of a table depending of the previous sorted column.
It works fine for the first two columns. But as soon as I sort the third column the second one loses its sort. As far as I know for now there must be a problem with my foreach loop. Here is my code for sorting:

```
public List<object> inhaltSortieren(List<object> zuSortierendeListe, Dictionary<string, SortierRichtung> sortierung)
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<object> sortierteListe = null;
    if (sortierung.First().Value == SortierRichtung.asc)
        sortierteListe = zuSortierendeListe.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sortierung.First().Key).GetValue(x, null));
    else if (sortierung.First().Value == SortierRichtung.desc)
        sortierteListe = zuSortierendeListe.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sortierung.First().Key).GetValue(x, null));
    bool first = true;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SortierRichtung> spalte in sortierung)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (spalte.Value == SortierRichtung.asc)
            sortierteListe = sortierteListe.ThenBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(spalte.Key).GetValue(x, null));
        else if (spalte.Value == SortierRichtung.desc)
            sortierteListe = sortierteListe.ThenByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(spalte.Key).GetValue(x, null));
    }

    return sortierteListe.ToList();
 }
```

Any ideas?

**Update:** Maybe I add some further information:

- @param zusortierendeListe: this is the List I want to sort, it is a List of Objects
- @param sortierung: This is the direction I want to sort, ascending or descending

The objects themselves are Lists of Tabledata

Comment: Your code is *conceptually* problematic - you're treating a `Dictionary<,>` as an *ordered* list. It's not.

Comment: Try replacing Dictionary<string, SortierRichtung> e.g. with List<Tuple<string,SortierRichtung>>.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing in a `Dictionary`; the order in which you get values out of a `Dictionary` when you use it as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` (as your `foreach` loop does) is (probably) *not* the order in which you added them!

You'll need to use a `List<KeyValuePair>` (or some other *ordered* `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`) instead of the `Dictionary`, or even create a custom class to hold the field and direction and pass a `List` of that.

Answer (score 1):

Also [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084671/linq-multiple-order-by)

Just to make your code a bit more clear. You can put everything into the for-each loop or leave it as it is, but then use sortierung.Skip(1) in your code, because you used the first entry already. I also changed the Dictionary argument to IEnumerable> according to the previous comment.

```
    object GetValue(object value, string name)
    {
        return value.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(value, null);
    }

    public List<object> SortContent(List<object> listToSort, Tuple<string, SortDirection>[] sortInfos)
    {
        if (sortInfos == null || sortInfos.Length == 0)
             return listToSort;

        IOrderedEnumerable<object> sortedList = null;

        foreach (var column in sortInfos)
        {
            Func<object, object> sort = x => GetValue(x, column.Key);

            bool desc = column.Value == SortDirection.Descending;

            if (sortedList == null)
                sortedList = desc ? listToSort.OrderByDescending(sort) : listToSort.OrderBy(sort);
            else
                sortedList = desc ? sortedList.ThenByDescending(sort) : sortedList.ThenBy(sort);
        }

        return sortedList.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This will still be broken if he passes in a `Dictionary` for the `IEnumerable` parameter. (Otherwise some good ideas :) )